# excel VBA how to click on onclick events of a div on IE11

Tags: excel, vba

i have searched and searched but have not find any solution to resolve this,

How do i fire an onclick event that is within a div? I am getting everything right by testing it with its title and getattribute but it just wouldn't click.

```
IE.document.getElementById("btn_header").FireEvent ("onclick")
IE.document.getElementById("btn_header").click
IE.document.getElementById("btn_header").parentElement.click
```

The Web code

```
<td>
    <div id='btn_header' title='BTN' onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank');"></div>
</td>
```

I also saw some site saying Fireevent doesn't work with IE11 for some reason, is there any other alternatives to it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`div.FireEvent "onclick"` should work (following example tested with IE11). 
Maybe your div is empty (contains nothing where could be clicked on?).

HTML used to test the code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/qzge2xy0/1/).

---

```
' Add reference to Microsoft Internet Controls (SHDocVw)
' Add reference to Microsoft HTML Object Library

Sub TriggerDivClick()
    Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim div As HTMLDivElement
    Dim url As String

    url = "file:///c:/temp/divOnClick.html"
    Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate url

    While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Wend

    Set doc = ie.document
    Set div = ie.document.getElementById("btn_header")

    div.FireEvent "onclick"
    ie.Quit

    Set ie = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Brilliant, so i must call HTMLDivElement to the job huh, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You might also try to call the script direct with:

```
IE.document.parentWindow.execScript "window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank');", "javascript"
```

Comment: YESS!!!! I've been looking around for hours to figure out how to do just that. You solved so many of my issues in one line.