# Trigger onclick event on IE with inherited ID

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, onclick

I'm looking to automate a web form filling spread through 3 different parts of the same form.
I cannot trigger the form continuation (second button) since it does not have a specific ID for the button it's ID is inherited from the "divclass" from above

This is the HTML portion of the buttons:

```
<div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10" id="divBtns">
                        <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="validarcredencial()" type="button">Siguiente</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-warning" onclick="setpaso(2, 'paso1')" type="button">Continuar sin credencial</button>
                    </div>
```

This is what I've tried so far:

```
'ie.document.getElementByClass("btn btn-warning").Focus
'ie.document.getElementByClass("btn btn-warning").Click
'ie.document.getElementById("divBtns").Click ("")
'IE.document.getElementsByID("divContent").Click
'IE.document.getElementsByTypeName("button")(1).Click
'IE.document.getElementsByTagName("divBtns")(1).Click
'IE.document.forms(0).submit

'Set AllHyperLinks = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("A")
'    For Each hyper_link In AllHyperLinks
'        If hyper_link.innertext = "Continuar sin credencial" Then
'        hyper_link.Click
'        Exit For
'    End If
'Next
```

Any help on how to trigger the button will be much appreciated

Comment: Update, I've tried this solution (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31221853/) which seems to be really close but still stuck since the solution is for a single button and am now getting an "Object doesn't support this property or method" on `Set class = ie.document.getElementByClass("btn btn-warning")` this is the code I ran: `Dim doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim div As HTMLDivElement
Set doc = ie.document
Set div = ie.document.getElementById("divBtns")
Set class = ie.document.getElementByClass("btn btn-warning")
div.class.FireEvent "onclick"`

Comment: Managed to click on the button but the page does not move forward to the next portion it just refreshes, the buttons have an ID for the are in their vicinity so I'm clicking there and sending keys (TAB,TAB,ENTER) form still not loading though `ie.navigate "http://afiliacionpt.org/afiliados/create"
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until ie.readyState = 4
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:1")

ie.document.getElementById("divBtns").Click
SendKeys "{TAB}"
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:1")
SendKeys "{TAB}"
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:1")
SendKeys "{ENTER}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out,

In case anyone has this same issue here's what to do.
So from the buttons I have; after I click anyone of the two, each would call a different javascript function.

(i.e. onclick="validarcredencial()" or onclick="setpaso(2, 'paso1')") so I just need to trigger the function from the button I need directly with:

```
IE.document.parentWindow.execScript "setpaso(2, 'paso1')", "javascript"
```

and voila, problem solved.